# Photoshop: preparing PDF files for spot color printing

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, print-production, pantone, spot-color

My working file is currently a two channel artwork in Photoshop, one black channel with one Pantone spot color channel over it. How do I prepare these files for press?

On PDF export it only shows a negative of the Pantone channel (which makes sense), but do I then just advise the printer to print of 100% K?

[image: "negative"]
[image: desired]

Thanks

Comment: I edited to make it clear this is a Photoshop question.

Comment: I do not understand "only shows a negative of the Pantone Channel" -- that seems incorrect and does *not* "make sense" to me. Are there overprints? Can you include some images (even just a small, cropped section) of how to two inks should interact?

Comment: @Scott - A negative is perhaps an inaccurate choice of word on my end. Exporting the Spot color channel from Photoshop results in a white background with the spot color filled in varying gray/black densities, which looks like a photo "negative" of the original. This might make sense considering the ink is to be printed over black? Added screenshots for reference.

Comment: That does make more sense... and *can* depend on what app you are using to view the resulting PDF. **Many** PDF viewers can't handle spots.. use Acrobat or Reader *only*. If you save the PDF to PDF/X-1a it *should* be correct.  Often the spot channel, on its own, does merely look like a greyscale channel. It's not *technically* a color until the ink goes into the press.

Comment: Using Acrobat it's rather easy to confirm the resulting PDF is correct.. there's the ink manager and tools for checking things.

Comment: When you say " it only shows a negative" - what software are you using to view the PDF?  Can you try Adobe Reader/Acrobat instead?